# Converting Continuous Model Probability Score to a Categorical Rating

Tags: machine-learning, probability, xgboost

I have a standard xgboost classification model that has been trained and now predicts a probability score. However, for the purposes of making the user interface simpler, I would like to convert this score to a 5 star rating scheme. I.e. discretizing the score.

What are intelligent ways of deriving the thresholds for this quantization such that the high ratings represents a high probability score with high confidence?

For example, I was considering generating the confidence intervals along with the prediction and grouping high confidence high score as 5 stars. High confidence low score as 1 star. High confidence medium high score as 4 star and so on.

Comment: can you provide a [MVCE example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @MaxU unnecessary for a MVCE. I was not looking for a code implementation. I just wanted intelligent techniques or directions of solving this problem. In any case, the problem is solved and already in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated multiple solutions for this and prototyped a V0 solution. The main requirements for the solution are as follows:

- As the rating level increases (5 star is better than 1 star) the # of false positives must decrease.
- The user doesnt have to manually define thresholds on the score probabilities and the thresholds are derived automatically.
- The thresholds are derived from some higher level business requirement.
- The thresholds are derived from the labelled data and can be rederived as new information is found.

Other solutions considered:

- Confidence interval based rating. For example, you could have a high predicted score of 0.9 but low confidence (i.e. large confidence interval) and a high predicted score of 0.9 but high confidence (i.e. small interval). I suspect we might want the latter to be a 5 star candidate while the former a 4* perhaps?
- Identifying Convexity and concavity of ROC curve to identify points of max value
- Use Youden index to identify optimal point

Final solution - Sample ROC curve with a given set of business requirements (set of FPR's associated to each star rating) and then translate to thresholds.
Note: This worked but assumes a somewhat monotonic precision curve which may not always be the case. I improved the solution by formulating the problem as an optimization problem where the rating thresholds were the degree of freedom and the objective function was the linearity of the conversion rates between each rating bucket. Im sure you could try out different objective functions but for my purpose that worked really well.

References:

- [Converting Continuous Model Probability Score to a Categorical Rating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218083/converting-continuous-model-probability-score-to-a-categorical-rating/49237472#49237472)
- http://www.medicalbiostatistics.com/roccurve.pdf
- http://www.bigdatarepublic.nl/regression-prediction-intervals-with-xgboost/

Prototype Solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# The probas and fpr/tpr/thresholds come from the roc curve.
probas_ = xgb_model_copy.fit(features.values[train], label.values[train]).predict_proba(features.values[test])
# Compute ROC curve and area the curve
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(label.values[test], probas_[:, 1])

fpr_req = [0.01, 0.3, 0.5,0.9]
def find_nearest(array,value):
    idx = (np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
    return idx

fpr_indexes = [find_nearest(fpr, fpr_req_val) for fpr_req_val in fpr_req]
star_rating_thresholds = thresholds[fpr_indexes]
star_rating_thresholds = np.append(np.append([1],star_rating_thresholds),[0])
candidate_ratings = pd.cut(probas_,
star_rating_thresholds[::-1], labels=[5,4,3,2,1],right=False,include_lowest=True)

star_rating_thresolds
array([1. , 0.5073538 , 0.50184137, 0.5011086 , 0.4984425 ,
0. ])
candidate_ratings
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, ..., 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
Length: 564
Categories (5, int64): [5 < 4 < 3 < 2 < 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

youcan use [`Pandas.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) method:

```
In [62]: np.random.seed(0)

In [63]: a = np.random.rand(10)

In [64]: a
Out[64]: array([0.5488135 , 0.71518937, 0.60276338, 0.54488318, 0.4236548 , 0.64589411, 0.43758721, 0.891773  , 0.96366276, 0.38344152])

In [65]: pd.cut(a, bins=np.linspace(0, 1, 6), labels=[1,2,3,4,5])
Out[65]:
[3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2]
Categories (5, int64): [1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5]
```

**UPDATE:** [@EranMoshe has added an important point - "you might want to normalize your output before cutting it into categorical values"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218083/converting-continuous-model-probability-score-to-a-categorical-rating/49218257?noredirect=1#comment85441013_49218257).

Demo:

```
In [117]: a
Out[117]: array([0.6 , 0.8 , 0.85, 0.9 , 0.95, 0.97])

In [118]: pd.cut(a, bins=np.linspace(a.min(), a.max(), 6),
                 labels=[1,2,3,4,5], include_lowest=True)
Out[118]:
[1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]
Categories (5, int64): [1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5]
```

Comment: Do note that in an output like this: [0.80, 0.85, 0.90, 0.95, .. ] (Where most of your score are at a certain level), you might want to normalize your output before cutting it into categorical values

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I was looking for the way to come up with the thresholds in the first place vs. how to code the transformation to a categorical column. For example, I was considering generating the confidence intervals along with the prediction and grouping high confidence high score as 5 stars. High confidence low score as 1 star. High confidence medium high score as 4 star and so on.

Comment: @SriK I don't see how this answer fails you. You said you have a model that gives you a prediction of how likely a certain event is of Class A or not. You want to present that probability as a 1-5 "star" rating. This answers your exact needs. If you want to set "thresholds", its more of a "Business" problem, where you look at the AUC ROC curve and decide how much  "False Positives" you are willing to suffer for a prediction

Comment: As the question explicitly states - "What are intelligent ways of deriving the thresholds ?" . The technique on how to set the thresholds is the core of the problem. The coding of it discretizing given a set of thresholds isnt the big issue. You mentioned ROC. How would the various cuts on the ROC be decided? Or does the confidence interval of the prediction be a better use to derive what are high confidence low/high scores vs. low confidence low/high scores. And then using that to set the ratings.

Comment: I dont see this as a simple "business issue". I think there are genuine automated techniques that can help come up derive a good set of thresholds. The techniques may have some parameters but it should be much more higher level than the score thresholds since those will change as the model is retrained, more training data, etc... Nevertheless thanks for your input and I would appreciate it if you removed your downvote since this is a valuable question to get answered for the community.

Comment: @Srik I almost never use the down-vote button, certainly not on a well put question :>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a classification problem: `either 1's or 0's`

When calculating the AUC of the ROC curve, you sort the "events" by your model prediction. So at the top, you'll most likely have a lot of 1's, and the farther you go down on that sorted list, more 0's.

Now lets say you try to determine whats the threshold of score `"5"`.
You can count the relative % of 0's in your data you are willing to suffer.

Given the following table:

```
item   A    score
1      1    0.99
2      1    0.92
3      0    0.89
4      1    0.88
5      1    0.74
6      0    0.66
7      0    0.64
8      0    0.59
9      1    0.55
```

If I want `"user score" "5"` to have 0% false positives I would determine the threshold for "5" to be above `0.89`

If I can tolerate 10% false positives I would determine the threshold to be above `0.66`.

You can do the same for each threshold.

In my opinion this is a 100% business decision and the smartest way to pick those thresholds is by your knowledge of the users.

If users expects `"5"` to be a perfect prediction of the class (life and death situation) go with the 0% false positives.

Comment: Thanks. Took your point about the business requirements. I actually extended this thought to completion and described a solution in another answer here. Am continuing to think through the idea of using FPR as the business requirement vs. perhaps absolute # of false positives.

Comment: @SriK, [there is a good way to say "thanks" on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @MaxU I just put my final system into production and it is working very well. The other answers are nowhere close to anything that helped me. No offense, but people who strongly claim to just know the answer and are ultra confident of themselves while sweeping all details away by stating "its just business requirements", a "thanks" is unwarranted. Confidence is not equal to expertise. The key insight here was to formulate it as an optimization problem where thresholds are the degree of freedom and the objective function can be a linear relationship between the rating conversion rates.